# Cannot assign to property: 'popupHeight' is a get-only property

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, viewcontroller

I got problems using [this cocoapod](https://github.com/ergunemr/BottomPopup).

I want to set the popupHeight for the popup, but it says "Cannot assign to property: 'popupHeight' is a get-only property"...

This is my code:

```
@IBAction func testBtnPressed(_ sender: Any) {
    guard let popupVC = storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "popup") as? BottomPopupViewController else { return }
    popupVC.popupHeight = 50.0 //ERROR!!!
    popupVC.popupDelegate = self
    present(popupVC, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

Can someone help me? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I just checked the link and the sample project. In sample project I can see that they have overridden named as `popupHeight`  on which you are trying to set a value like this :- `override var popupHeight: CGFloat { return height ?? CGFloat(300) }` you can lear more about the `get and set` [here](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/Properties.html).

For now what you can do is simply in your `BottomPopupViewController` you can simply override this `popupHeight` variable and set the value which you want. or else you can do in similar way they have done in the example.

For that :- take a variable named `height` or any thing you want like this :- `var height: CGFloat?` and then set it while instantiating your View controller like this :- `popupVC.height = 50.0` and have the overriden method in your `BottomPopupViewController`  this one :- `override var popupHeight: CGFloat { return height ?? CGFloat(300) }` basically it would take the height you will be setting in here `popupVC.height = 50.0`